# Check if char is one of these chars !@#%&()-_/.,;':"\][{}

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to check if the current character in a TextBox in WPF is of !@#%&()-_/.,;':"][{}  this type.

I want to convert all the keyboard into a specific character and so far only those characters are not covered by my code.

So far i'm using

```
if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(Convert.ToChar(tb.SelectedText)) || (char.IsSymbol(Convert.ToChar(tb.SelectedText))) || (char.IsSeparator(Convert.ToChar(tb.SelectedText))))
```

Comment: isn't that just simple like this `if("!@#%&()-_/.,;':\"][{}".Contains(yourChar))`?

Comment: @Hopeless well i can check for those chars manually but it seems stupid. Also what if the user has another keyboard configuration with some additional chars. I want to check for every chars that you can create with a keyboard, not just a specific keyboard

Comment: at least that's what I understand about your question. Now looks like your problem is to prevent some chars from being typed, but if you're not sure about all kinds of possible chars, then you should know just which chars are allowed, if you don't even know that then I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: You're talking about keys and characters. Those are different things. One key being pressed, depending on previous and simultaneous keypresses, can lead to different characters. Please explain your original problem thoroughly. Do you maybe want to _accept_ only alphanumeric characters in your input?

Comment: You want to get rid of all non alphanumeric characters ?

Comment: Use a whitelist instead. Check for the characters that are ok, instead of checking for the characters that are not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:
    char.IsPunctuation(char c)